# Preimages of evenly covered basis gives a basis?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}_X), (Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ be topological spaces, and let $p : Y → X$ be a covering map. Then there exists some open cover $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_X$ such that every $U ∈ \mathcal{U}$ is evenly covered by $p$, i.e. for every $U∈ \mathcal{U}$ there is a set $\mathcal{V}_U \subseteq \mathcal{T}_Y$ of pairwise disjoint open sets such that $p^{-1}U = \sqcup_{V ∈ \mathcal{V}_U}V$, and that $p|_V : V \tilde{→} U$ is a homeomorphism for each $V ∈ \mathcal{V}_U$.

Now, I have seen the following claim going around which in my understanding should be wrong (although it probably isn't).

The first part of the claim is there exists an evenly covered *basis* $\mathcal{B}_X$ for $X$; the second part is that $\bigcup\limits_{U ∈ \mathcal{B}_X} \mathcal{V}_U$ forms a basis for $\mathcal{T}_Y$.

Consider the topological space $(X, \{\emptyset, X_1, X_2, X\})$. Suppose $X_1 ∪ X_2 = X$, but they are not disjoint. Then $\mathcal{U} = \{X_1, X_2\}$ is an open covering of $X$. Say that we have $\mathcal{V}_{X_1} = \{V_1, V_2, V_3 \}$ and $\mathcal{V}_{X_2} = \{W_1, W_2, W_3 , W_4\}$ so that $\mathcal{U}$ is in fact an evenly covered basis for $\mathcal{T}_X$. In the definition of covering spaces, there is no demand on the $V_i$ to not-overlap with a $W_j$. Note that as $X_1 ∩ X_2 ≠ \emptyset $, we have  $\emptyset \neq p^{-1}(X_1 ∩ X_2) = p^{-1}X_1 \cap  p^{-1}X_2 = \sqcup_{i=1}^3 V_i \cap \sqcup_{i=1}^4 W_i$.  So at least some $V_i$ overlaps with some $W_j$. Say, $V_1 ∩ W_1 ≠ \emptyset$. $V_1$ and $W_1$, however, being open sets in $Y$, must result in $V_1 ∩ W_1 ∈ \mathcal{T}_Y$. But this is in contradiction with the claim that $\bigcup\limits_{U ∈ \mathcal{B}_X} \mathcal{V}_U$ forms a *basis* for $\mathcal{T}_Y$, because we can never get the open set $V_1 ∩ W_1$ by taking unions of elements not strictly smaller than $V_1$ and $W_1$!

What's going on here?

Comment: $X_1 \cap X_2$ must belong to the topology. Your $\mathcal U$ is not a base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is wrong. We shall use notation (e.g. *sheet structure* and *sheet number*) and basic results from [Covering projections: What are the sheets over an evenly covered set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3835771)

The claim says that

1. There exists an evenly covered basis $\mathcal B_X$ for $X$.
2. For each $U \in \mathcal B_X$ let $S(U)$ be a sheet structure over $U$. Then $\mathcal{B}_X^Y = \bigcup\limits_{U \in \mathcal{B}_X} S(U)$ forms a basis for $Y$.

Note that in general the sheet structure over $U$, i.e. the decomposition of $p^{-1}(U)$ into sheets, is not unique. Non-uniqueness always occurs if $U$ is not connected with sheet number $> 1$. In that case we actually have to **choose** a sheet structure over $U$. This means that $\mathcal{B}_X^Y$ in general is not uniquely determined by $\mathcal{B}_X$, but involves a **choice** for each non-connected $U \in \mathcal{B}_X$ with sheet number $> 1$.

Now let $X = \{0\} \cup \{1/n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb R$ and $Y = X \times \mathbb Z$. Let $p$ be the projection; this is a covering map. Since $X$ is evenly covered, also each open subset of $X$ is evenly covered.

Let $\mathcal B_X$ be any basis for $X$. Each $U \in \mathcal B_X$ has a maximal element $x_U \in U$ with respect to the natural order of $X$. Of course $x_U > 0$ since $\{0\}$ is not open.

For $k \in \mathbb Z$ define $V_k(U) =( U \setminus \{x_U\}) \times \{k\} \cup \{(x_U,k+1)\}$. Then the $V_k(U)$ form a decomposition of $p^{-1}(U)$ into sheets.

We claim that the collection $\mathcal B_X^Y  =\{V_k(U) \mid U \in \mathcal B_X, k \in \mathbb Z\}$ is not a basis for $Y$.

The set $X \times \{0\}$ is an open neigborhood of $(0,0)$ in $Y$. If $\mathcal B_X^Y$ were a basis for $Y$, then $X \times \{0\}$ should contain some $V_k(U)$ with $(0,0)  \in V_k(U)$. The latter is satisfied iff $k = 0$ and $0  \in U$. However, $(x_U,0)$ is not contained in $V_0(U)$. This is a contradiction.

So what can be said *positively*?

> If $X$ is locally connected, then it has a basis $\mathcal B_X$ of evenly covered open connected sets. For each such basis, $\mathcal B_X^Y$ is a basis for $Y$. In particular, $Y$ is locally connected.

Note that each evenly covered open connected set $U$ has a *unique* sheet structure $S(U)$ over $U$, thus no choice of a decomposition of $p^{-1}(U)$ into sheets is involved. Therefore in the above case $\mathcal B_X^Y$ is uniquely determined by $\mathcal B_X$.

Let $W$ be an open neigborhood of $y \in Y$. Let $U' \subset X$  be an evenly covered open set such that $p(y) \in U'$. Choose any sheet structure $S(U')$ over $U'$. There exists a unique $V'_y \in S(U')$ such that $y \in V'_y$. The set $W' = W \cap V'_y$  is an open neigborhood of $y$ and $U'' = p(W') \subset U'$ is an open neigborhood of $p(y)$. We have $W' \in S(U') \mid_{U''}$. There exists $U \in \mathcal B_X$ such that $p(y) \in U \subset U''$. The restriction $(S(U') \mid_{U''}) \mid_U = S(U') \mid_U$ is the *unique* sheet structure $S(U)$ over the connected $U$. Let $V = W' \mid_U \in S(U)$. Then $y \in V = W' \mid_U \subset W' =  W \cap V_y \subset W$ and  we are done.

Another positive result is this. For an open evenly covered $U \subset X$ let $S^*(U)$ be union of all sheet structures over $X$ (in other words, it is set of all open $V \subset p^{-1}(U)$ which are [plain over $U$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3835771)).

> Let $\mathcal B_X$ be a basis of $X$ consisting of evenly covered open sets. Then $\bigcup\limits_{U \in \mathcal{B}_X} S^*(U)$ forms a basis for $Y$.

The proof is almost the same as the above proof for locally connected $X$. We get again $y \in V = W' \mid_U \subset W' =  W \cap V_y \subset W$, but now $V \in (S(U') \mid_{U''}) \mid_U \in S^*(U)$.