# Group Action and Second-Countability

Tags: general-topology

Let $G$ be a finite group acting freely on a Hausdorff space $X$ so that for each $g \in G$, the map $x \mapsto g \cdot x$ is a homeomorphism. Since in this case, the natural projection $p:X \rightarrow X/G$ is open (for, if $U$ is an open subset of $X$, then  $p^{-1}(p(U))= \bigcup_{g \in G} g U$ is open in $X$, and so $p(U)$ is open in $X/G$), it is easy to see that if $\{ B_i \}_{i \in I}$ is a base for the topology of $X$, then $\{ p(B_i) \}_{i \in I}$ is a base for the topology of $X/G$. In particular, if $X$ is second-countable, so is $X/G$.

My question is: does the reverse hold? In other terms, if $X/G$ is second-countable, can we deduce that $X$ is second-countable?

For now, I could not answer this question neither in the positive nor in the negative, so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's well-known that if $G$ is a finite free action, then $p:X\to X/G$ is a covering map. See for example [here](https://math.ucr.edu/%7Eres/math205C-2011/freeactions.pdf).

It's known that in case of covering maps $E\to Y$, the basis of $Y$ can't in general be translated to a basis of $E$ by using sheets of evenly covered sets, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3834914/476484). The reason is that such decomposition won't be unique. But if $Y$ is locally connected, then such decomposition is unique, and given a basis of evenly covered connected sets, the sheets will also form a basis. Moreover, this will imply that $E$ is locally connected. The converse, that $E$ being locally connected implies that $Y$ is locally connected holds for any quotient map, so this is the same as saying that $E$ is locally connected.

Thus, with the additional assumption that $X$ is locally connected, it suffices to show that if $X/G$ is second-countable, then $X/G$ admits a countable basis of connected evenly covered open sets, since sheet of any evenly covered open set is of size $|G| < \infty$. By taking a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $X/G$ consisting of evenly covered connected open sets (this is possible since if $x\in V\subseteq U$ and $U$ is evenly covered, then $V$ is evenly covered), we can find a countable basis $\mathcal{B}_0\subseteq \mathcal{B}$ (see Engelking theorem 1.1.15).

Thus we obtain:

**Theorem.** Let $X$ be a locally connected $T_2$ space, and $G$ a finite free action on $X$. Then $X$ is second-countable iff $X/G$ is second-countable.

Comment: Dear Jakobian, I want thank you very very ... much for having kindly answered my question. From a first quick reading, it seems to me that you got a remarkable result. I had quite a feeling that local connectedness should play a role in building a basis for $X$, but I could not articulate a precise reasoning by myself. I have not yet accepted your answer, because I want to study all of its details, which I shall do in the next days, when I will have some spare time.

Comment: In the meantime, my impression is that your result is tight, in the sense that if we drop the local connectedness assumption, we should be able to find an example where $X/G$ is second-countable, but $X$ is not. Anyhow, my reserve of "strange" topological spaces is very limited, so I do not think to be able to come up with such a counterexample.

Comment: No problem, I've mostly collected a bunch of results that I found, it's Paul Frost and others that really deserve the most credit. As for tightness of this result, I honestly don't know. Alessandro Codenotti mentioned that he can't find an example of a map $f:X\to Y$ with finite fibers such that $Y$ is second-countable but $X$ isn't, and I can't either.

Comment: Dear @Jakobian, I have carefully read your answer, and it struck me as very brilliant: I could never give it by myself! I barely know the definition of covering map! So thank you very very ... much! I accepted it as an answer to my question, even though it actually does not really answer it! In order to give a complete answer, one should be able to find an example of an $X$ which is not second-countable, with $X/G$ second-countable. Clearly, such an $X$ must be not locally connected.

Comment: Anyhow, in order to find such a counterexample (which I strongly believe exists), one must have a wide knowledge of "pathological" spaces, which could provide a counterexample (or most probably) inspire its construction. Unfortunately, my knowledge of general topology is too superficial to tackle such a task. Maybe someone else could suceed!

Comment: @MaurizioBarbato It's not just that, covering maps just don't come up in general topology often, so I don't think you'd find much about this in literature, they are more relevant in algebraic topology and such.